# Laravel - return text stored from DB without the default formatting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to return some text stored within the database, but without the current formatting of brackets and quotations that appears to be included when I get the row from the DB:

> ["Aut ducimus et deleniti quaerat. Autem minima amet et totam et
>   incidunt culpa. Ullam enim est maxime veniam expedita aut. Magni
>   tempora autem iste repudiandae quisquam. Libero nisi delectus incidunt
>   aut rerum incidunt."]

**Database seed:**

```
public function run()

    {
      $faker = Faker\Factory::create('en_GB');

      $terms = [[
        'terms' => $faker->paragraph(3)

      ]];

      DB::table('miscellaneous')->insert($terms);

    }
```

**Controller.php:**

```
$terms = Miscellaneous::where('id', 1)->pluck('terms');
```

**View:**

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="15">{{ $terms }}</textarea>
```

How can I output the `raw` text that's stored within the DB like such:

> Aut ducimus et deleniti quaerat. Autem minima amet et totam et
>   incidunt culpa. Ullam enim est maxime veniam expedita aut. Magni
>   tempora autem iste repudiandae quisquam. Libero nisi delectus incidunt
>   aut rerum incidunt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eloquent `pluck()` returns an array containing the data from one column of each row. If you select a single row, the attributes can be used to access to the right column.

Try this (suppose that column **id** is the primary key):

```
$terms = Miscellaneous::findOrFail(1)->terms;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `pluck` which retrieves an array containing the values of the column you're plucking.

Instead, you can grab just the `value` of `terms` from the record, which will provide you what you want:

```
$terms = Miscellaneous::where('id', 1)->value('terms');
```